# Turbogears tutorials , debugging tools

Tags: python, turbogears

I successfully installed turbogears via virtualenv on ubuntu , loaded it with paster after quickstart. I was looking for a good ide with debugging for turbogears and paster. I need any good suggestion how to continue with , any good tutorials , links etc , ide information would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: pycharm is the best ide for python, IMO http://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would checkout [Wing IDE](http://www.wingware.com/doc/howtos/turbogears). The personal version runs 35 bucks.

Answer (score 3):

Pydev - Eclipse can be setup for free and easy debugging

http://pydev.blogspot.com/2006/07/configuring-pydev-to-work-with.html